# Is there a way to obtain ModelMetadata.Properties for ModelMetadata.RelatedEntities?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, t4, scaffolding

I've been reading up on the [Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding.Core.Metadata](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.scaffolding.core.metadata(v=vs.118).aspx) namespace; however, I am new to this object model and perhaps I am overlooking something.  I am creating T4 text templates and would like to auto-generate output for related model data.  Something akin to ModelMetadata.RelatedModelMetadata.ModelMetadata.PropertyMetadata i.e.

```
foreach (PropertyMetadata property in ModelMetadata.Properties) {
  if (property.IsAssociation) {
    RelatedModelMetadata relatedModel = property.RelatedModel
    foreach (PropertyMetadata relatedProperty in relatedModel.Properties) {
      // Do Something
    }
  }
}
```

This of course won't work as the [RelatedModelMetadata](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.scaffolding.core.metadata.relatedmodelmetadata(v=vs.118).aspx) object has no Properties collection; in fact all of the RelatedModelMetadata properties are strings.

Any tips are tricks you may have are appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Mark, Have you ever found a solution for this requirement in T4?
I have tried using Reflection to get the property of the type name string of the RelatedMetadata object but that does not work as the T4 runs in its own application space. I can find no way to construct a Scaffolding.Core.Metadata object for the RelatedModel. I can only use the EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude tools and then load the total EntityFramework edmx file, but this binds my T4 model to the EntityModel and it cannot be re-used for generating Controllers in another project.

Comment: @FrancoisGrobler Any way to get Scaffolding.Core.Metadata object instantiated outside T4 template?

Answer (score -2):

In your view generation template, you can access the `Model.ModelMetadata.Navigations` property. This is "similar" to RelatedModelMetadata... I repeat "similar" in quotes... the similarity is perhaps more in intent, than in functionality.

```
@foreach (var property in Model.ModelMetadata.Navigations)
{
   //I do what I want!
}
```

Each `property` gives you the properties

- AssociationPropertyName : *string*
- DisplayPropertyName : *string*
- EntitySetName : *string*
- ForeignKeyPropertyNames : *string array*
- PrimaryKeyNames : *string array*
- ShortTypeName : *string*
- TypeName : *string*